# Post your answer blocked due to closed question

Tags: feature-request, answers, closed-questions

Recently I was writing a quite large answer on Stack Overflow. When I finished I found out that the  "Post your answer" button was blocked because the question got closed.

I understand the fact that there is no case to answer a closed or bad question. But, what if I think I got the answer for that person?

Why can't we leave an answer (not visible) on that question, in case it gets reopened again?

Comment: A question being closed indicates that there are significant issues with that question. Those need to be resolved first before you can answer, partially to protect answerers from wasting time on a question that might significantly change.

Comment: A rarely known fact (that I learned from hanging around in Meta) is that you can still post your answer, by re-enabling the "Post Your Answer" with jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best possible solution in this case would be to blog your answer somewhere or [post it over any pastebin service](http://pastebin.com/) or post it somewhere it makes sense and then leave a comment with a link to it. This way, you won't feel that your whole effort was a waste and you would have helped that person as well.

Otherwise, if you feel that there is a case to re-open the question (it should be justified):

- [vote to re-open if you have the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions), or
- flag it for moderators as *Other* and provide the reason for re-opening, or
- post it on Meta with your justifications.

Comment: Ok, it seems the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I rolled you over 1000.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Haha.. Thank you :)

Comment: Yet another approach would be a self-answer, if you're good at asking.