# New feature proposal: move 'closed' questions to a "Recycle Bin"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

Whenever a question is 'closed' in any of the Stack Exchange forums, for ANY reason, it instantly becomes locked: i.e., it is not answerable anymore.

Now, some questions could be edited and then re-opened, some could be migrated, but in many cases, nobody knows how to make a question better; the only thing that they know is, "it doesn't belong here". Most users who post such questions are new and are not accustomed to the narrow, stringent on-topic guidelines, or read the guidelines, thought that it would be on-topic, but it turned out that it is not. (Okay, many people do not read or research anything, but they should not determine how the others get treated!)

Not only this affects the asker's account, but also, more than that, it gives off a "you're not welcome here" vibe. As a result of this negative experience, it might discourage some to ask questions in the future, or drive them away forever.

Given that how overworked Moderators are and how frustrating their tasks could be, plus, as a community-oriented set of forums, I think every question and every asker should, at least, have an **oppurtunity to be judged by the community** as a whole.

I propose that there should be a "Recycle Bin" ("What's in a name?") in every Stack Exchange forum, to where a closed question automatically goes, and stays there for, say, 30, 60, or 90 days, or until re-opened, after which it gets deleted. While in the "Recycle Bin", it is answerable. The "Recycle Bin" link would be in the left side navigation panel.
Optional: "Recycle Bin" up-votes give more positive reputation, and, possibly, special badge(s).

---

In its current form, it's just one or a few people who decides what the rest gets to see! (I admit that they have earned it, but we are all humans, and prone to errors and biases.)
As Stack Exchange strives to be a democratic forum, I think that separating those questions from the mainstream (you'll see them if you choose to see them), and those still being answerable, would be a good idea.

What if this is tried as a beta? If it turns out to be fruitless, it could be stopped anytime.

---

The suggested question (and the linked ones to that) is asking that the question stay in the "main area". I am asking that it be moved to a place of its own, eligible to get answers, and still be deleted after a time period if not clarified well enough to return to the "main area".
As of now, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177756/865622) is the only way (for a kind-hearted) to answer a closed question, which is not very "Stack Exchange-y"!

**N.B.:** As with any opinions, there always are people who think that a question is valid, or it makes sense to them, and/or would like to help. I am asking about giving everybody a chance before deleting forever.

Comment: If the question was closed because it was unclear or overly broad, how will moving it to a recycle bin fix that? Why should such questions be answerable in that state?

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange! Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, on questions requesting new features, voting [is used to signify agreement or disagreement with a given proposal](/help/whats-meta), so if your question gets downvoted, it may just mean that people disagree with your proposal, not necessarily that your question is bad for the site.

Comment: The majority of questions are closed by non-moderators. They already have been judged by the community, and found wanting of significant if not impossible change before they are suitable. You have totally missed the purpose of closure, which is to actively prevent answers to an ill-formed question, that then become invalid or unhelpful because they cannot or do not adequately address the entirety of the question. You also don't seem familiar with closed questions that can still be voted on, whether up or down, and for reopening or deletion, along with flagging as always.

Comment: And while Sonic's comment is accurate, and you will get many votes from users signifying "I think this is a bad idea", you will also get at least one downvote for showing no research effort on what closing a question is for and what it does to a question.

Comment: This will make sense for **deleted** questions, where high rep users will be able to easily see recently deleted questions and undelete if they see fit, maybe "undelete review" and not recycle bin. But for closed questions this makes very little sense.

Comment: I know that closed questions could be flagged, nominated for re-opened, or editing within 5 days puts it in a review queue, etc. I was not aware that it could be voted. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: In any case, it is not answerable. That is exactly why it should be in a "sandbox" type region, away from the mainstream, and still have some hope to give _some_ help to someone in need. I personally think that it will be good for building a stronger user base, while keeping those "unwanted" questions away from those who don't want it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow posting answers for "on hold" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229167/allow-posting-answers-for-on-hold-questions)

Comment: If it's not answerable then it's up to the OP to edit it into a state where it is answerable. We can't add missing information, nor can we fix the scope of overly broad questions, only the OP can do that. IMHO nobody would visit that dumping ground of bad questions so it would be the same as delete in all but name.

Comment: "If it's not answerable ..." May be, it is answerable, may be someone gets it and now wants to answer it, but cannot, because some people thought that "it doesn't belong here" and closed the question.

Comment: _someone getting it_ is not really a good reason to allow posting answers, see eg [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601). Also consider having a look at [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601) "Don't ever answer an off-topic question, not via chat, comments, or any other way. It is even dangerous to say: go here, Google for that, because next time, they will do the exact same and eventually get what they want."

Comment: @a_das - If you find a closed question you can answer you should edit it and vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 6):

> As of now, this is the only way (for a kind-hearted) to answer a closed question, which is not very "Stack Exchange-y"!

Answers do not belong in comments. The advice the answer you linked to gives is pretty bad for even suggesting it. And you're right, answering in comments isn't very 'Stack Exchange-y'.

But neither is allowing any type and any kind of question, no matter how badly written, to get an answer. The whole 'Stack Exchange-y' point of closing questions is that they will not get any (more) answers until they are improved to fit the guidelines and topic of whatever site they were asked on.

Your recycle bin, while a noble idea, goes against a lot of Stack Exchange-y' things. If all off-topic questions would end up in a recycle bin and become answerable again, I predict it would quickly turn into a place for [joke questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/26/joke-questions-please-refrain/) about [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19487/369802). I predict it would be filled with questions that aren't related to the site's subject at all.

Awarding people reputation for answering such questions in a recycle bin would create another problem: right now, reputation is supposed to be an indicator of how well you know the site or its subject matter. It's not very 'Stack Exchange-y' to get reputation and moderation privileges for a site that focuses on cooking by answering questions in the recycle bin about sex education (just to use an example of a question I closed and deleted this morning).

And, if 'closing' a question doesn't discourage any answers, what incentive does a question asker have to improve their question and possibly get their answer? Even more, what incentive do people have to even close them, instead of answering them and gaining some reputation points on the site itself? If questions that are unclear are allowed to have answers, how can we be sure an answer makes the right assumptions on where the problem lies?

> As with any opinions, there always are people who think that a question is valid, or it makes sense to them, and/or would like to help. I am asking about giving everybody a chance before deleting forever.

Wanting to help is nice. But it's not 'Stack Exchange-y' to do so by circumventing the system and posting your answer in a comment, or by arguing that everything should go because you might be able to/willing to help.

Closed questions aren't usually deleted instantly, unless they're very blatantly off-topic and/or bordering on being rude/abusive. The community and the writer of that question are given a few days to work together, so you can help by helping people improve their questions.

You can also help by suggesting 'better' sites if you know them. Usually a question does need more polishing before being worth migrating, but if you see one that could be improved and posted on a different site, work with the OP to achieve a good post for that site.

If neither of the two is an option, perhaps it's time to realize that Stack Exchange isn't the suitable place online to find or provide the kind of help needed. There are other places on the internet that are less strict. For example, some of the posts that wouldn't float on Interpersonal Skills SE would probably do great on Reddit's Am I The Asshole.